# How to get the IndexPath of a selected cell as soon as it is pressed in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have been trying to get the IndexPath of the currently selected row. I have been using this function:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPathForSelection: IndexPath) {
            print(SavedColors.SavedColorsList[indexPathForSelection.row].Name)
    }
```

The problem is that it gives me the IndexPath of the cell that was just deselected. If I press the first cell, nothing happens. If I then press the second cell, it prints "0" the indexPath of the first cell, and so on. I want to get the index path as soon as a cell is pressed. How do I do this?

Said another way: the function is called when the selection is switched to another cell, but not when a cell is selected. I want the user to tap, and the funtion to activate. Instead, when you tap, nothing happens, until you tap another different cell. How can I fix this?

I don't know if this is related, but the `self.tableView.deselectSelectedRow(animated: true)` function isn't doing anything either...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use didSelect rather than deSelect

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPathForSelection: IndexPath) {
            print(SavedColors.SavedColorsList[indexPathForSelection.row].Name)
    }
```

.

DidSelect calls when you select a cell and deSelect calls when you un select a cell ... so be careful when you are writing these functions happy coding =)

Answer (score 0):

sorry but i don't quite catch your question

if you really just want to get the indexPath when you get a tap on certain cell, you could conform

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: I improved the question. tell me if this makes sense! thank you.

Comment: @qwerty-dvorak The answer is correct. You should not confuse "didSelectRowAt" with "didDeselectRowAt" or with "deselectSelectedRow".